# как очистить корзину после отправки заказа?

Tags: php

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "отправить" очищалась корзина и выводилась надпись "спасибо за заказ"

```
case 'completion':

            echo'
            <div id="block-step"> 

            <div id="name-step">

            <ul>
            <li><a href="cart.php?action=oneclick">Корзина заказов</a></li>
            <li><span>&#8594;</span><li>
            <li><a href="cart.php?action=confirm">Контактная информация</a></li>
            <li><span>&#8594;</span><li>
            <li><a class="active">Подтверждение</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>

            ';

    if ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'yes_auth')
    {
        echo '
       <ul id = "list-info">
       <li><strong>Способ доставки: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_delivery'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Способ оплаты: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_payment'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Email: </strong>'.$_SESSION['auth_email'].'</li>
       <li><strong>ФИО: </strong>'.$_SESSION['auth_surname'].''.$_SESSION['auth_name'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Адрес доставки: </strong>'.$_SESSION['auth_address'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Телефон: </strong>'.$_SESSION['auth_phone'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Примечание: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_note'].'</li>
       </ul>
        ';
    }else
    {
        echo '
       <ul id = "list-info">
       <li><strong>Способ доставки: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_delivery'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Способ оплаты: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_payment'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Email: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_email'].'</li>
       <li><strong>ФИО: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_fio'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Адрес доставки: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_address'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Телефон: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_phone'].'</li>
       <li><strong>Примечание: </strong>'.$_SESSION['order_note'].'</li>
       </ul>

     ';   
    }
     echo'
     <h2 class="itog-price" align="right">Итого: <strong>'.group_numerals($itogpricecart).'</strong> руб.</h2>
      <p align="right" class="button-next"><a href="">Отправить</a></p>

        ';
```

Comment: Для начала покажите как формируется корзина и что она из себя представляет вообще

Comment: Могу скинуть код на почту

Comment: Код лучше выложить здесь, не бойтесь, никому он не нужен по сути, чтобы использовать в своих целях, он нужен лишь для всестороннего обзора и предложения лучшего решения от нескольких участников данного сайта.

Comment: да он большой файл превышает количество допустимых символов

Comment: Покажите фрагмент, в котором есть кнопка **отправить**, и как Вы пытаетесь выводить сообщение.

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую! Попробуйте:

```
unset($_SESSION['name']); // Для удаления данных сессии
```

Или

```
session_destroy(); //
```

Comment: если использовать unset($_SESSION['name']); // Для удаления данных сессии то необходимо в каком то конкретном месте это использовать? (в начале в конце?)

Comment: @Daria Там где данные уже не нужны. После того как они отправлены.

Comment: не получается, корзина как была полная  так и осталась,может еще какой нибудь способ посоветуйте

Comment: @Daria откуда данные в корзину приходят? Вы сессию как очищаете? За место `'name'` указываете свои переменные?